# Keyframe Issue in blender

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor, dopesheet, timeline

[image]I have an object which is accidently got animated. I have other objects in the scene but only that particular object is moving up and down as I scroll timeline. I can see an orange line under timeline but I can not see any keyframe. I tried to delete keyframes by several ways but no use and that orange line is also not disabled. I checked other objects which are not animated and they don't have that orange line in timeline.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you've got something acting on it like physics, a modifier, or constraint perhaps?

Comment: I have added Images. Please check. If there is any issue in physics or in a modifier or in constraint then can we edit it in timeline? If so please tell the process because I am new to blender and I tried all possibilities what you suggested but could not find anything.

Comment: In addition to Edgel3D comment, it looks like you have baked something like rigid body. Could you provide the .blend file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This yellow line represents some type of baked movement like rigidbody , or a constraint , to have a look if this is the problem , you can click on the Physics properties tab 2nd block from the modifiers , their if you see a rigidbody constraint , you need to click the cross to remove it and then start your timeline from the first frame .

Comment: Thanks Edgel3d, Mugnozzo,Shikha Mittal for your replies. The problem is solved. It was due to rigid body. Just now, when I started blender that object was not at that place :D. Hence, I found it by cursor first, then relocated it, set its origin reset scale and removed rigid body from  object menu > regid body >  remove. Luckily, I found rigid body in that menu. Huh!! Thanks all for your support.

Comment: you can select the tick mark below the voting in my answer to declare this answer correct